# Email over smtp from Laravel using outlook/office365 business email

Tags: php, laravel, email, outlook, smtp

I am trying to send an email over smtp from Laravel using outlook business email. I am using TLS 1.2, And I activated SMTP settings for email from admin center active users panel, and I am using the following:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
# MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
# MAIL_HOST=smtp-legacy.office365.com
# MAIL_HOST=smtp-legacy.partner.outlook.cn
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@site.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="app_password" #from MFA
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="email@site.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But I am having this error: `with message \"535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful`. Note that the commented MAIL_HOSTS are links I tried with the same result.

Also I tried port 25 with error `Connection could not be established with host \"smtp-mail.outlook.com:25`

Note that I am using this Laravel's mailer:

```
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN'),
        ],
```

Any fix?

Comment: As laravel can use various mailers, which are you using

Comment: I point you at the microsoft website page about accessing their SMTP Servers. Note the Encryption setting for 365! [POP, IMAP, and SMTP settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353)

Comment: STARTTLS is exactly  tls @RiggsFolly

Comment: Did you just try changing the param to see if the error was different?

Comment: Sure I did MAIL_ENCRYPTION=starttls, with same result

Comment: and `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),`

Comment: Shouldn't it get updated when I change env file and `php artisan config:cache`??

Comment: Note I am using app_password now instead of password